# Chrome/Opera jquery css display not working

Tags: jquery, css, google-chrome, opera

I want to show a floating text message whenever the user clicks on certains html elements; the code is

```
function avviso(el, e){   
    var y = e.pageY;
    var x = e.pageX;
    saved_state = classi[classi.length - 2]; 
    msg = $("#messagge");
    $(msg).css('display', 'block');
    $(msg).css('top', y-80).css('left', x);
    $( "<p>\""+el.textContent+"\"</p>").appendTo(msg);
}
```

Attached to the elements like this:

```
$(span).on("click tap", function(event){
      var element = this;
      avviso(element, event);
 }).mouseleave(function(){
      $("#messagge").css('display', 'none');
      $("#messagge").children().remove();
 });
```

Where span is the element to be clicked and "#messagge" is the id of the text message that should appear, initialized with the following css properties:

```
    var n= $("<div id='messagge'></div>");
    var styles = {
            "display" : "none",
            "position":"absolute",
            "background-color":"#fff",
            "border":"1px solid #000",
            "padding":"5px",
            "max-width":"200px",
            "color":"black",
            "font-size":"10px",
        }
        $(n).css( styles );
        $(n).appendTo($("body"))
```

Now, everything works fine in all browsers, with the exceptions of chrome and Opera, where the message does not appear. If I don't change the display property into "none" on mouse leave there is a small white square appearing where I click, but with no text inside.
I assumed it has something to do with the .css("display", "block"), but I'm not really sure of it (sorry if the title does not match my problem). Maybe I am missing some portability issue?

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow.. It would really help us to understand, try, and solve your problem if you post a jsfiddle in your question. Here is the link if you never did it: https://jsfiddle.net/

Comment: How did you make `var new = ...` work in firefox? It's syntax error.

Comment: I changed it while writing the question, the actual code works - edited it now, sorry

Comment: What is this line about? `saved_state = classi[classi.length - 2];`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I suggest that the problem is this: when you click on the span element the message appears below the mouse pointer, instantly triggering mouseleave event which hides the message. Try to comment out mouseleave event callback to see if that is the problem. Also play with top/left values here:

```
$(msg).css('top', y-80).css('left', x);
```

Add or remove some values to x/y to be sure that your div with message does not appear under the cursor.

Comment: Exactly that, added 20 to the x value and work perfectly now. I doubt I'd ever came up with the solution by myself, thanks a lot

Comment: If my answer resolved your issue then accept it please.

Comment: Sorry, my first question on StackOverFlow, forgot to do it

Answer (score 0):

As spotted by [Serge Seredenko](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32417426/chrome-opera-jquery-css-display-not-working/32417492#comment52701277_32417426) in comments, you're using the `new` reserved word to name a var. This automatically throws a syntax error.

I don't think you made this work in any browser or JS engine.. Try changing it to `_new` or something like that..

---

#### Update

With that var changed, and removed this (I think unrelated) line

```
saved_state = classi[classi.length - 2];
```

It works perfectly. Here is a jsfiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/jormaechea/4b7r66vr/

Comment: Was a copying mistake, it has another name in the actual code, edited it now

Comment: @Maldus Just edited my answer. Check it out. If the problem is still there, you didn't post the right chunk of code.. (I tested it in Chrome, BTW)

Comment: It works now, looks now the problem was the one pointed out by ischenkodv